# How do I force links to secure content (mainly images) in new posts

Tags: wordpress, security, mixed

In short - I want to force all content of new posts to link to secure sources. Team members were instructed to refrain from including links to non secure sources, but this sometimes slips them (mainly with new images), leading to pages being displayed as having mixed content. When they do, I usually see it and fix the links manually. However, I would like to prevent this from happening altogether so links to external resources are always checked to be secure. Is there a way to enforce it?

Comment: Well, what keeps you from checking links? Where do they enter them? What technologies are used? How is content presented? What have you tried after researching how it could be done? ... I think this question needs a lot more details before it can be answered.

Comment: Fair enough. It's a WP site that has a lot of team members generating new posts on a daily basis (about 5 a day), with images being part of the posts. If these images are from non secure sources, the page is shown as having mixed content in the post. 
I prefer not to keep monitoring these manually. Instead, I would like the site script to prevent adding images from non secure sources (either by setting or by a plugin), which would force the team member to look for an image from a secure source (usually it would just mean they'll need to rename the link from http to https).